# How can I share hyperlinks when using the Android Sharesheet?

Tags: android

Using the Android sharesheet, I am unable to parse HTML to create hyperlinks. This used to be possible in previous Android versions.

Here is the code I am using to do this. I have tried setting `text/html` to `message/rfc822`. I am aware that apps have to add support for html parsing but after trying several mail apps, I haven't found a single one that creates a hyperlink. They either disregard the HTML overall or paste it with no formatting.

I have also tried removing `Html.fromHtml` and removing `Intent.EXTRA_HTML_TEXT`. The HTML renders just fine on my PC. Is this just not possible in modern Android versions? The only app I have found that allows for hyperlinks is the default Android mail app which probably has very little usage.

```
Intent.createChooser(Intent().apply {
        action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
        this.type = "text/html"
        content?.let {
            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml("This is a test Visit <a href=\"https://www.google.com\">google</a> for more info."))
            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_HTML_TEXT, "This is a test Visit <a href=\"https://www.google.com\">google</a> for more info.")
        }
        previewTitle?.let {
            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Sharing Test")
        }
        thumbnail?.let {
            clipData = ClipData.newUri(contentResolver, null, thumbnail)
        }
        flags?.let {
            this.flags = it
        }
    }, null)
```

Comment: If you remove the `Intent.createChooser()` part, do you get different results? If you use `ShareCompat.IntentBuilder`, do you get different results?

Comment: @CommonsWare I just tried those and no luck. Tried Gmail, Zoho Mail, Yahoo Mail and they do not have hyperlinks in any of the main mailing applications. I also tried a few big apps such as Uber Eats, MS Office, Rover, Twitter, Ring, Shopify and all of their sharing functionality does not use hyperlinks.